# MVCSiteMapProvider - System.Windows load issue

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version of the MVCSiteMapProvider and having issues. Some context, I can't use Nuget so have cloned using git, built in release mode locally and copied the relevant assemblies to my project depedencies folder, adding references to MvcSiteMapProvider.dll, Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll and to WebActivatorEx.dll.

Because it's a working app, I can't, as the text files with the source suggests, just copy the unity folders/file across. I have though wired up the container as follows (roughly):

```
public class UnityRegistrar
{
    public UnityRegistrar()
    {

      container = new UnityContainer();
      container.AddNewExtension<MvcSiteMapProviderContainerExtension>();
    }
}
```

Where the extension class is based on https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/tree/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/CodeAsConfiguration/Unity/DI/Unity/ContainerExtensions

Various type maps are registered in Unity and the following code is the last thing to execute.

```
MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Loader = container.Resolve<ISiteMapLoader>();
```

The net result is that I get the following type load exception: 
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:

*Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

None of the three dll's referenced depend on this assembly, so I'm unsure as to what I've done wrong. Needless to say a vanilla project with references added via nuget without IoC configured through Unity works. Removing the MvcSiteMapProvider start up/IoC code from my app doesn't however, so not sure what I've done wrong here.

Any thoughts on why it's asking for System.Windows.dll?

**EDIT**

More detail on error : 
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +371
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +19
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +319
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) +203
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +1179
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +146
   WebActivatorEx.AssemblyExtensions.GetActivationAttributes(Assembly assembly) +113
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +290
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods(Boolean designerMode) +47
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +70

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +12600191
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +12599912
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +280
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12599232
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12438981

It's related to the use of WebActivatorEx. If I remove the reference, and clean up the bin dir, it doesn't blow up. I don't use WebActivator to and PostApplicationStartMethod to construct my container. I've a method in global.asax which boostraps my container.

Not sure why WebActivatorEx is asking for System.Windows given it's not a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The root of my problem with System.Windows load exception was due to assemblies lying around in the bin dir that didn't belong there. In some one's wisdom, they included a post build task to copy all dependencies to the bin, including those not referenced by the project. Hence why there were System.Windows.*.dll in the bin dir of a web project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a full stack trace of where the exception occurs? Can you try analyzing fusion logs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: had a look in fusion log viewer but it didn't tell me much.

Comment: Editted original question. Removing WebActivator gets me moving forwards. If I drop the dll in to the bin though, without a reference in the proj, it blows up again.

Comment: Can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737363/after-upgrading-to-net-4-0-im-getting-the-exception-could-not-load-file-or-a ?

Comment: Thanks. Looking into it. Could be a separate dependency that's overlapping and causing an issue. Will confirm after further investigation.

Comment: Several reference to System.Windows.Controls.*dll seem to be causing the issue, but still trying to track the origin of the dependency. It's not immediately obvious but I know which dll's are causing the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

> built in release mode locally

Based on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737363/after-upgrading-to-net-4-0-im-getting-the-exception-could-not-load-file-or-a) provided by @maartenba, I suspect this is where your problem lies, because you need to have the compiler switches and framework version setup correctly for all of the dependencies to work right. Not to mention, they need to match what you have in your project exactly.

First of all, make sure you run your build off of the **master** branch.

If you run the **build.bat** file, passing it the version and package version switches you will be able to build all of the versions the same way they are built for the NuGet packages. Then you can be sure all of the dependencies are set up correctly for your .NET framework version.

```
(From the same directory as the MvcSiteMapProvider.sln file)
(NOTE: Use the current version on NuGet Gallery, this version is only current at the time of this writing)

MvcSiteMapProvider>build.bat -pv:4.4.9 -v:4.4.9
```

Note that this fires off a powershell script, so you may need to run [this command](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider#building-the-source) to setup powershell correctly. See [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2702/setting-the-powershell-execution-policy/) for more details.

After you run the build, you will be able to access both the raw DLL files and the .nupkg files (if you want to install them locally via NuGet) in the **\release** folder. The DLLs can be found at

```
(From the same directory as the MvcSiteMapProvider.sln file)
\release\mvcsitemapprovider.mvc[X].core\lib\net[YY]\MvcSiteMapProvider.dll
```

Replace the X with your MVC version and the YY with your .NET framework version (example use 40 for 4.0, or 45 for 4.5).

The .nupkg files are at the root of the **\release** directory and are named using the same conventions used on NuGet gallery.

On a side note, if you "cannot use NuGet" because you cannot access the Internet from your dev or build machine, do note that it is possible to access the .nupkg file from a local directory by going into "Settings" from the main NuGet GUI window and then adding a "package source" mapping to your own file system. If you mean you "cannot use NuGet" because you are afraid of breaking your DI configuration, note that the Unity "modules only" packages are designed for this very purpose - they only give you a module to integrate with your existing DI configuration, while leaving your main wiring code intact. You just need to add a few lines to your existing configuration to get the wheels turning - see the [readme file for Unity](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/tree/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/CodeAsConfiguration/Unity/DI/Unity). Of course, you may have another reason for not using NuGet, but just wanted to be sure you (and the community) were aware of these points.

Comment: Thanks NightOwl. I made some progress on the issue with the WebActivator and System.Windows.Controls.*dll. That problem has now gone away, and it appears my DI changes (so far are ok). I read the readme and took the parts of the Unity configuration that didn't conflict with my existing code base. I've now got some interesting issues with the route and site map node not matching. Different problem. Thanks for the heads up. In terms of not being able to use Nuget, it's purely a long standing CI issue, and ripple effect on CI, build and deploy. A challenge to tackle another day.

Comment: For any node matching problems, I recommend reading this post: http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position